# Including "isdtp" URL parameter will make sforce.console.isInConsole() return TRUE

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, urlhacking, console

I found this funny "issue" the other day and I want to share it here. It's maybe a good reminder why we shouldn't use "hacks" that Salesforce doesn't support.

Let's say you have a Visualforce page that is used inside and outside of Salesforce Console. It will probably have a `sforce.console.isInConsole()` check somewhere in the JavaScript code, similar to TestPage below.

**TestPage.vfp**

```
<apex:page >  
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/42.0/integration.js"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function(){
            if(sforce.console.isInConsole()){
                alert("In Console");
            }else{
                alert("Not in Console")
            }            
        }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

This will work fine until you include the `isdtp=mn` parameter hack to hide the header and sidebar of the page. With this parameter included the `sforce.console.isInConsole()` will always return `true`, which will probably break your logic.

Actually, if you set this URL parameter to any other value (e.g. - `isdtp=whatever`), the same behavior will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used to resolve this issue quickly was to check if my page is inside an iframe. If the page is in iframe, that means, in my case at least, that the page is used inside the Salesforce Console.

**Updated TestPage.vfp**

```
<apex:page >  
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/42.0/integration.js"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function(){
            if(sforce.console.isInConsole() && inIframe()){
                alert("In Console");
            }else{
                alert("Not in Console")
            }            
        }

        function inIframe () {
            try {
                return window.self !== window.top;
            } catch (e) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

---

However, a probably better solution would be to not use the URL hacking at all, but to instead mark **TestPage** with `showHeader="false"` and  `sidebar="false"` to hide the header and sidebar in a normal way. Then you can create another "wrapper" page to show the header and sidebar when required.

**TestPageWrapper.vfp**

```
<apex:page >  
    <apex:include pageName="TestPage"/>
</apex:page>
```